# How to adapt script to work with parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I've got the following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onresize = resize;
  var sizes = [2880, 1920, 1000, 600];

  function resize() {
    //console.log('si');
    var img = $('img.resizable');
    var width = $(window).innerWidth();
    img.each(function(index, element) {
      var name = element.src.split('/');
      name = name[name.length - 1];
      var setto = 0;
      for (var i = sizes.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        //console.log(i,width,setto, sizes[i]);
        if (width <= sizes[i]) {
          setto = sizes[i];
          break;
        }
      }
      setto = width >= sizes[0] ? sizes[0] : setto;
      $(element).attr('src', 'images/' + setto + '/' + name);
    });
  }
  resize();
});
```

It works with IMG tags: `<img src="images/August-Vision-Night.png" class="resizable" alt=""/>`

I'm trying to adapt it to work with a parallax background image.  Instead of changing `src` it needs to change `data-image-src`

`<div id="contentsection_1_container" class="parallax-window parallax-resizable" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/texture-clouds.png">`

I attempted the following code; however, it didn't work at all.  I'm new to this, so I have no clue how to actually fix the script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onresize = resize;
  var sizes = [2880, 1920, 1000, 600];

  function resize() {
    //console.log('si');
    var img = $('.parallax-resizable');
    var width = $(window).innerWidth();
    img.each(function(index, element) {
      var name = element.data-image-src.split('/');
      name = name[name.length - 1];
      var setto = 0;
      for (var i = sizes.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        //console.log(i,width,setto, sizes[i]);
        if (width <= sizes[i]) {
          setto = sizes[i];
          break;
        }
      }
      setto = width >= sizes[0] ? sizes[0] : setto;
      $(element).attr('data-image-src', 'images/' + setto + '/' + name);
    });
  }
  resize();
});
```

Comment: Your code does what you believe should be done. However, it's very likely that whatever you're using for parallax scrolling only uses the `data-image-src` value when it starts. It isn't monitoring it for any changes.

Comment: any idea of a solution for this?

Comment: I couldn't tell you. There's somewhere in the ballpark of 1,375,289 parallax plugins and I don't know which one you're using.

Comment: I don't think something is right though.  Its not loading an image at all...even though it worked before I added this script.